# typescript number returns string as typeof

Tags: javascript, typescript

I created a `numericQuantity` variable which is a casted string `quantity`, is there an explanation why logging the **typeof** returns *string* even when the variable has a **:number** type?

```js
let quantity: string = '10';
let numericQuantity: number = quantity as unknown as number;

console.log(typeof quantity);  // string
console.log(typeof numericQuantity);  //string
```

I tried this on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEHUFMBsGMHsC2lQBd5oBYoCoE8AHSAZVgCcBLA1UABWgEM8BzM+AVwDsATAGiwoBnUENANQAd0gAjQRVSQAUCEmYKsTKGYUAbpGF4OY0BoadYKdJMoL+gzAzIoz3UNEiPOofEVKVqAHSKymAAmkYI7NCuqGqcANag8ABmIjQUXrFOKBJMggBcISGgoAC0oACCbvCwDKgU8JkY7p7ehCTkVDQS2E6gnPCxGcwmZqDSTgzxxWWVoASMFmgYkAAeRJTInN3ymj4d-jSCeNsMq-wuoPaOltigAKoASgAywhK7SbGQZIIz5VWCFzSeCrZagNYbChbHaxUDcCjJZLfSDbExIAgUdxkUBIursJzCFJtXydajBdw0ACO7DM9VQeHyV1QlE4IwAvKAAOQARgADJyANyKCn9djISiwACKNO28gZosQ0m+oA51NpcrEwi48QGEi8DGEnDFSrIQsUCE4gng7gC0HgzAAFPSiES1bL6QBKIUWq02u2O52QIlG8XqaXqz1m4o4ZoeMheRDwPoMYHsGhfNxmZg05iQfiwaDqRIp+B6EReABEAFFVgxEAt9BWktiK+AHKhOcIAHKQCQVoIqADyXzI70Eea0kCOqEcClc0jwoCciZ0wyw+hQCEQ0OElwzEiT0REBg42IWTFYHB4QRKQA) and got the same result.

Comment: Because its still a string. There is no cast in typescript, there are only type assertions.

Comment: I see, I also tried the opposite, casting number to string in which I get autocompletion but if I try to use for instance .length it returns undefined, does it mean it is not preferable to use "casting" in typescript

Comment: TypeScript doesn't have "casting" the way you're thinking of it (so it doesn't matter whether it's *preferable* or not, unless you're just talking about terminology, in which case, yeah, the *term* "casting" should be avoided).  Using `as` is a *type assertion*, where you are telling the compiler what type a value is.  It has no runtime effect.  If you say `"abc" as unknown as number` you are not doing anything at runtime; all you're doing is *lying to the compiler* about what type `"abc"` is.  Type assertions are predictions, not actions or commands.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `quantity as unknown as number`, that only helps to satisfy the typescript compiler when you know that code is correct and working but the type system won't allow it.

`typeof` is not a typescript operator that returns the declared type. It's a javascript operator that returns the type of the runtime value. And your `numericQuantity` variable holds a string.

If you actually want to write a program that [converts the string value to a number value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1133770/1048572), instead of assigning `numericQuantity = quantity` but asserting the compiler "I know better than you, this is actually a number", then write

```
const quantity = '10';
const numericQuantity = Number(quantity);

console.log(typeof quantity);  // string
console.log(typeof numericQuantity);  // number
```