# TypeScript Declared 'number' everywhere but still getting 'string' back. What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In React I am learning to use TypeScript properly. Declaring types wherever I can.

Recently, I had a hiccup. Neither TypeScript or VS Code could detect this "error / warning". I had to dig in myself. I am curious to know where do we draw the line between TypeScript and IDEs helping us and where we need to do our own thing?

```js
// I need this to be a number.
const [bill, setBill] = useState(0);

// Receive user input. Save in state. Yes! I can say Number(amo) but took me 20 mins to figure that out :)
function handleNewBill(amo: number) {
    setBill(amo);
  }

// In my component. Stating that I am expecting a number
type AppProps = {
  bill: number;
  updateBill: any;
};

export default function Bill({ bill, updateBill }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <h4>How much was the bill?</h4>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={bill}
        onChange={(e) => updateBill(e.target.value)}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

I understand e.target.value returns a "string" but neither TS, nor VS code "picked" this up. Am I missing something or is this how it's supposed to be? TS is taking more time than it's helping. I am not questioning large scale multi-programmer codebase, but for smol hobby projects does it make sense? Or do I need a plugin for VS Code to pick something up like this?

[This response was interesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75655269/typescript-number-returns-string-as-typeof).

> "...asserting the compiler "I know better than you, this is actually a number", then write..."

Comment: Why use a `text` input if you expect a number? If you change it to `type="number"` you can use `e.target.valueAsNumber`

Comment: _`updateBill: any;`_  why this? Where is `handleNewBill` used?

Comment: Yeah, the thing you're missing is [`any` turns off type checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#any).  You might want to include that in your answer since you just showed how you fixed it but not why the problem occurred in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Phil! valueAsNumber is interesting. I will check it out. Still learning, missing some basic JS knowledge it seems.

updateBill runs the state function in the parent component. My terminology with callbacks is also a bit weak.

jcalz yes, will include that note.

Answer (score -1):

The solution was a lot more complicated to not make mistakes like this :)

In the Component Bill

```js
type AppProps = {
  bill: number;
/* updateBill: any; // Was the original solution */
  updateBill: (amo: number) => void; // Notice this line, specifically say it expects amo as number. ONLY then the below e.target.value will be highlighted in RED showing string is being taken in! Add Number(e.target.value)
};

export default function Bill({ bill, updateBill }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <h4>How much was the bill?</h4>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={bill}
        onChange={(e) => updateBill(Number(e.target.value))}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Typing `updateBill: any;` properly would probably fix the error

Comment: @Konrad you are right, that's what I had initially. But e.target.value would come in as string and not number, no RED highlight in VS Code. In my above sol, I stated exactly what the function was expecting...